# Add target="_blank to my code? (Won't work)

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
<a href="http://www.moddb.com/downloads/start/121000?referer=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.moddb.com%2Fmods%2Fthe-great-conqueror%2Fdownloads"><img src="http://thegreatconqueror.weebly.com/uploads/8/5/2/5/85251306/download.png" onmouseover="this.src='http://thegreatconqueror.weebly.com/uploads/8/5/2/5/85251306/download2.gif'" onmouseout="this.src='http://thegreatconqueror.weebly.com/uploads/8/5/2/5/85251306/download.png'" /></a>
```

I know I need a target="_blank, but it won't work anywhere I place it.. Please help!

Comment: what is your requirement?

Comment: I just want the link to open in another tab.

Comment: where **have** you placed it - nowhere in the html you posted - hint, it's a `<a>` attribute

Comment: <a href="http://www.moddb.com/downloads/start/121000?referer=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.moddb.com%2Fmods%2Fthe-great-conqueror%2Fdownloads" target="_blank"><img src="http://thegreatconqueror.weebly.com/uploads/8/5/2/5/85251306/download.png" onmouseover="this.src='http://thegreatconqueror.weebly.com/uploads/8/5/2/5/85251306/download2.gif'" onmouseout="this.src='http://thegreatconqueror.weebly.com/uploads/8/5/2/5/85251306/download.png'" /></a> try this

Comment: <a href="http://www.moddb.com/downloads/start/121000?referer=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.moddb.com%2Fmods%2Fthe-great-conqueror%2Fdownloads" target="_blank">
<img src="http://thegreatconqueror.weebly.com/uploads/8/5/2/5/85251306/download.png" onmouseover="this.src='http://thegreatconqueror.weebly.com/uploads/8/5/2/5/85251306/download2.gif'" onmouseout="this.src='http://thegreatconqueror.weebly.com/uploads/8/5/2/5/85251306/download.png'" />
</a>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this...

```
<a href="http://www.moddb.com/downloads/start/121000?referer=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.moddb.com%2Fmods%2Fthe-great-conqueror%2Fdownloads" target="_blank">
<img src="http://thegreatconqueror.weebly.com/uploads/8/5/2/5/85251306/download.png" onmouseover="this.src='http://thegreatconqueror.weebly.com/uploads/8/5/2/5/85251306/download2.gif'" onmouseout="this.src='http://thegreatconqueror.weebly.com/uploads/8/5/2/5/85251306/download.png'" /></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="http://www.moddb.com/downloads/start/121000?referer=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.moddb.com%2Fmods%2Fthe-great-conqueror%2Fdownloads" target="_blank"><img src="http://thegreatconqueror.weebly.com/uploads/8/5/2/5/85251306/download.png" onmouseover="this.src='http://thegreatconqueror.weebly.com/uploads/8/5/2/5/85251306/download2.gif'" onmouseout="this.src='http://thegreatconqueror.weebly.com/uploads/8/5/2/5/85251306/download.png'" /></a>
```

I guess you placed it at the wrong place